# Does SQLBackup2Azure delete the blobs as well?

Tags: sql-server, blob, azure-vm

I am not sure if this questions belongs here or in server fault, apologies if it belongs there.  I am using MS SQL 2012 on an azure VM, and am planning on utilizing the `SQLbackup2Azure` tool to store the backup files directly in blob storage.  Does anyone know if deleting the stub files locally on the server will also trigger the azure storage service to delete the storage blobs?  My hunch is that it will not and that I should utilize a powershell script (like  [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-Storage-Blobs-that-aae4b761) one) to remove them after a time.

Comment: If you are on SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU2 or higher you can use `Backup to URL` instead of an external utility.

Comment: Hi, you are correct, but there is still no method of automated cleanup from SQL Manager. The maintenance tasks do not support a 'cleanup from URL' type of operation. I am using Ola Hallengren's scripts which also support backing up to a URL. However the script's cleanup parameter is not supported when backing up to a URL either. I am interested specifically in a better cleanup operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experimented with the tool and confirmed that deleting the stub files does not delete the Azure blob.  I had to set up a PowerShell script to cleanup the file blobs.